# Multithreading - Killing a Thread and all its child processes

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on an analytics app. in Java.At the top i have a GUI which has START and STOP Buttons.On Clicking Start i create a Thread inside whose RUN method i call an API method which internally creates a Thread.i.e.

On Clicking "START"----->a Thread is Spawned---->in this thread's RUN method i use an API cal which creates a thread Internally...

Now,what i want is that when i click the STOP GUI button,the internal thread created by the API call should also die..

How can i achieve that??

Thanks

Comment: Does the API provide any methods to kill/stop a thread?

Comment: Yeah,i got one explicit thread shutdown method for all internal threads:)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement some logic to the thread classes. First, they need some "kill switches" - you can't (shouldn't!!) stop them from outside. We usually define and set a flag on the thread instance so that it knows, when it has to terminate.

Then, we don't have a thread "hierarchy". A thread instances will need to its own list of *child threads* and, if it (the parent) receives the stop signal, it will have to send the same signal to its children.

```
public abstract class MyThread extends Thread {

   private List<MyThread> children = new ArrayList<MyThread>();
   private boolean stopNow = false;  // <- this is the stop flag

   public void stopNow() {
     for (MyThread thread:children) {
       thread.stopNow();
     }
     stopNow = true;
   }
 }
```

(This will not make a thread stop actually, we'll have to "monitor" the `stopNow` flag in the `run` method).

Comment: but my problem is that i can't get hold of a reference to that Thread,it is generated internally by the API call.

Comment: What does the thread do, what is passed in the API call?  Maybe you can change something that will cauise that 'hidden' internal thread to except/fail.

Comment: you just pass the starting info. once and then a thread is created which carries on its own..i need a considerable amount of info. hence i need to pass a legit input at the start.

Comment: Following Martin's comment - does the thread use any resource (db? file?) that you can alter to cause it to fail, rather than what you pass in at start time?

Comment: The thread uses realtime tweets from around the world...switching off the internet connection ain't gonna help because then it again would log errors saying no internet connection,which i do not want...